# Editing answered questions' tags to broaden audience

Tags: discussion, serial-editing

There's a sub-2000 point user editing the tags on questions already with satisfactory accepted answers (for rep, I presume) just by adding an extra tag referring to something mentioned in the question. In isolation the edit is borderline OK, but I feel he might be spamming up the review queue or front page with inconsequential editing.

Last Friday I successfully flagged him for fiddling with the tags on his own question - six edits in a couple of days - but am I spamming up the mod queue by reporting trivial matters?

Comment: If it's the same user doing it over and over, you shouldn't need to raise multiple moderator flags—a single one will alert them to the problem, and then they can reach out to the user and ask him to stop.